# Redirection in json code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, redirect

Am not a json geek but really need your help. During form submission & after successful validation, the following code is executed thus returning a 'registration successful' message.
I want it to be able to redirect to another page instead of returning that 'registration successful' notification.

```
$json_response = array(
    'status'  => 'success',
    'message' => $success_message,
);
$json_response = json_encode( $json_response );
echo $json_response;
```

I tried replacing the text with

```
header('Location: http://localhost/successful.php');
```

But in vain, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a server-side redirect from an AJAX request. You need to return that data, and then redirect in the `success` handler of your javascript.

Something like this in jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
   url: '/foo/',
   success: function(data) {
       if (data.status == 'success') {
           window.location.assign('/newpage'); // <- redirect at this point 
       }
       else {
           console.log(data.message);
       }
   }
});
```

Comment: It's actually possible to redirect on the server-side, but the redirection will only happen within the AJAX request.

Comment: @ComFreek yes, that's what I meant. If you do the redirect on the server side the returned value of the request will be the HTML of the redirected page.

Comment: Okay, that's a quick one let me give it a try. It's actually a wordpress plugin am modifying. Thanks